# Why does my string token gain a newline at its final reduction in my c++ bison program?

Tags: c++, newline, bison, flex-lexer

I'm writing a parser using flex and bison for a college assignment. At the moment, my goal is to read expressions made up of integers, strings, and their operators. The integers work well - the problem is with the strings. After I run the program, when I type a string into the console, it's supposed to print back the result of the expression - in this case that it's a string type, followed by the value of the string. So if I type "hello", I'm supposed to get back "it:String="hello"". The problem is that at my LAST reduction in the bison file (where bison uses one of the start variable's rules to reduce to the start variable), the string value somehow gains a newline at the end of it. So the string ends up being "hello\n", and so it:String="hello"\n is printed to the console. I've confirmed via the parse trace that the string value is correct until the last reduction, and then it gains that newline, and I can't figure out why. I think the problem will be perfectly clear with some code snippets.

Here is the important part of the lex file. The last rule is where I return a STRING token.

```
%{
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
using namespace std;
void yyerror(char*);
%}

%%

0                       { yylval.iVal = atoi(yytext);
                          return INTEGER;
                        }

[1-9][0-9]*             { yylval.iVal = atoi(yytext);
                          return INTEGER;
                        }

[-+()~$^*/;\n]          return *yytext;
"=="                    return EQ;
"!="                    return NE;
"&&"                    return AND;
"||"                    return OR;
"\""[^"\""]*"\""        { yylval.strVal = yytext;
                          return STRING; }
```

Here is the yacc file. When applying the rule "program: program strExpr '\n' ", that's where I print the response to the console.

```
%token EQ NE AND OR STRFIND
%token<iVal> INTEGER
%token<strVal> STRING
%left OR
%left AND
%left EQ NE
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%left UNARY
%right '^'

%{
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <string>
    #define YYDEBUG 1
    using namespace std;
    void yyerror(char *);
    int yylex(void);
%}

%union {
    int iVal;
    char* strVal;
}

%type<iVal> intExpr
%type<strVal> strExpr

%printer {fprintf(yyoutput, "%s", $$);} strExpr

%%

program:
    program intExpr '\n'         {cout<<"it:Int="<<$2<<"\n";}
    | program strExpr '\n'       {cout<<"it:String="<<$2<<"\n";}
    | program intExpr ';'
    | program strExpr ';'
    | program intExpr ';' '\n'
    | program strExpr ';' '|n'
    | program '\n'
    | program ';'
    | program ';' '\n'
    | ;
expr:
    intExpr
    | strExpr

intExpr:
    INTEGER
    | '-' intExpr %prec UNARY          { $$ = $2 * (-1); }
    | '+' intExpr %prec UNARY          { $$ = $2; }
    | intExpr '+' intExpr              { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | intExpr '*' intExpr              { $$ = $1 * $3; }
    | intExpr '-' intExpr              { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    | intExpr '/' intExpr              { if ($3 == 0) {
                                           yyerror(0);
                                           return 1;
                                       } else
                                           $$ = $1 / $3; }
    | '(' intExpr ')'                  { $$ = $2; }
    | intExpr '^' intExpr              { int i;
                                         int val = 1;
                                         for (i = 0; i < $3; i++) {
                                             val = val * $1;
                                         }
                                         $$ = val;
                                       }
    | intExpr EQ intExpr               { if ($1 == $3)
                                             $$ = 1;
                                         else
                                             $$ = 0;
                                       }
    | intExpr NE intExpr               { if ($1 != $3)
                                             $$ = 1;
                                         else
                                             $$ = 0;
                                       }
    | intExpr AND intExpr              { if ($1 != 0 && $3 != 0)
                                             $$ = 1;
                                         else
                                             $$ = 0;
                                       }
    | intExpr OR intExpr               { if ($1 != 0 || $3 != 0)
                                             $$ = 1;
                                         else
                                             $$ = 0;
                                       }
    | ;

strExpr:
    STRING                             
    | '(' strExpr ')'                  { $$ = $2; }
    | ;

%%

void yyerror(char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
}

int main(void) {
    yydebug = 1;
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output of a sample run:

```
"hello"
it:String="hello"

1+1
it:Int=2
3+4
it:Int=7
```

What's with that extra newline after it:String="hello"?

And here's the parse trace, which tells me the newline is being added on right before that last reduction, but I'm at a loss as to *why?*

```
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reducing stack by rule 10 (line 45):
-> $$ = nterm program ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 1
Reading a token: "hello"
Next token is token STRING ()
Shifting token STRING ()
Entering state 4
Reducing stack by rule 25 (line 93):
   $1 = token STRING ()
-> $$ = nterm strExpr ("hello")
Stack now 0 1
Entering state 11
Reading a token: Next token is token '\n' ()
Shifting token '\n' ()
Entering state 29
Reducing stack by rule 2 (line 37):
   $1 = nterm program ()
   $2 = nterm strExpr ("hello"
)
   $3 = token '\n' ()
it:String="hello"

-> $$ = nterm program ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 1
Reading a token:
```

I'll sure appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yylval.strVal = yytext;
```

`yytext` is a pointer that points to a static buffer. The buffer content will change each time a token is read.

```
yylval.strVal = strdup(yytext);
```

This will get rid of the newline, but of course introduce a memory leak. You need to take care of it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Is it sufficient to do free($2) right after I print in the bison file?

Comment: I guess it will be sufficient, but you really should try and tidy up your grammar. You have lots of near-duplicate rules, unused rules, and unnecessary conflicts. What's with all the `| ;` things?